# Any way to get SharePoint to STOP converting attachment file names to all lower case on inbound emails?

Tags: sharepoint, email, filenames, lowercase

I have a document library that is successfully receiving and saving attachments from inbound emails. The problem is that it is taking my nice, mixed-case file names and converting them to all lower case. I have looked on the Internet for a solution and only found a bunch of "me too" people with the same issue. Is there any way to control this behavior? Since the file name becomes the link text it would be nice if SharePoint left it alone.

Comment: not to nitpick, but what's wrong with all lowercase file names?

Comment: Interesting observation.  Sounds like a nice bug to me.  I wonder if Sharepoint does this to allow direct comparison of 2 filenames for duplicates.. since Windows won't allow 2 files to contain the same name (regardless of case).

Comment: Because when you are emailing an attachment to a document library, the file name becomes the link text. So if you have a document library that is holding a series of "chapters" in a manual, each document being one chapter, then since the file names are converted to all lower case, the link texts are all lower case, too. So instead of a link reading "How to Install the Frappinator", you get "how to install the frappinator."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known bug according to:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/0daedbf4-ddd1-4dd9-b7f0-70c03dc4afc4/

(links to the update packages are there, too)

Comment: Thanks, Vinny. We are putting on the Feb. 2009 CU this morning. I must not have come up with the right Google search terms to find that.

Comment: No worries - I'm interested in hearing how it goes (as I'm sure are the guys on technet up there). Does the change take effect immediately after restart for all libraries? Only for newly-created libraries, (God forbid) the problem persists, etc.

Comment: The change workd and took effect after restart for all libraries. Thanks again.